# Illegal Argument Exception

Tags: java, class, illegalargumentexception

I am working on a really simple point class but I am getting an error and I can't pinpoint where the String/double problem is happening or how to fix it.

```
public String getDistance (double x1,double x2,double y1,double y2) {

            double X= Math.pow((x2-x1),2); 
            double Y= Math.pow((y2-y1),2); 

            double distance = Math.sqrt(X + Y); 
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#####");

            String pointsDistance = (""+ distance);

             pointsDistance= df.format(pointsDistance);

            return pointsDistance;
        }
```

and the test code

```
double x1=p1.getX(),
                       x2=p2.getX(), 
                       y1=p1.getY(),
                       y2=p2.getY(); 

           pointsDistance= p1.getDistance(x1,x2,y1,y2);
```

**EDIT**

I forgot to add the error I'm receiving:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Number
at java.text.DecimalFormat.format(Unknown Source)
at java.text.Format.format(Unknown Source)
at Point.getDistance(Point.java:41)
at PointTest.main(PointTest.java:35)
```

Comment: Fortunately, you don't have to pinpoint the error since your compiler will do that for you...  Where is `p1`, `p2`, and `pointsDistance` defined?  What type is `p1` and `p2`?  I assume `pointsDistance` is a `String`.  What does `getX()` and `getY()` return on whatever object type `p1` and `p2` are?  Which line is `Point.java, line 41`?  Which is `PointTest.java line 35`?

Comment: pointsDistance= p1.getDistance(x1,x2,y1,y2);
is line 35

Comment: pointsDistance= df.format(pointsDistance); is line 41

Comment: So, there are two posted answers that explain that answer, but without the problem being obvious to me (I'm not a Java guru), the compiler has given me enough information to know that I should probably do some research on the `DecimalFormat` class and know what kind of arguments the `format` method expects.  After all, the error is `ILLEGAL ARGUMENT EXCEPTION` and points you straight to this line.

Answer (score 3):

You passed a `String`, but [the `format` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#format%28double%29) expects a `double` and returns a `String`.  Change from

```
String pointsDistance = (""+ distance);
pointsDistance= df.format(pointsDistance);
```

to

```
String pointsDistance = df.format(distance);
```

Comment: I have run your `getDistance` method, with my change, and I no longer get the error.

Comment: Technically there is a `format` that takes `Object` as a parameter (inherited from `Format`).  Hence the runtime error instead of compile.

Comment: @user2954611 Are you passing a `double` to the `format` method?

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
String pointsDistance = (""+ distance);

pointsDistance= df.format(pointsDistance);
```

with:

```
String pointsDistance = df.format(distance);
```

The problem is that your number format doesn't accept a string.

Comment: @user2954611 - Did you change the argument to `df.format()`? It is important to pass a `double`, not a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the [format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#format%28double%29) method takes a numeric value, not a `String`. Try the following:

```
public String getDistance(double x1, double x2, double y1, double y2) {
    double X = Math.pow((x2-x1), 2); 
    double Y = Math.pow((y2-y1), 2); 

    double distance = Math.sqrt(X + Y); 
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#####");

    String pointsDistance = df.format(distance);
    return pointsDistance;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
String pointsDistance = df.format(distance);
```

as the format method expects a `double` and not a `string`.

Answer (score 1):

Check out here first:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#format(double,%20java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.text.FieldPosition)

Does your use of format method same as that?